# How to raise an exception in render

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this following exception handler in my controller

```
  def call(conn, opts) do
    try do
      super(conn, opts)
    rescue
      e in Ecto.CastError -> conn
      |> put_status(:not_found)
      |> render(ErrorView, "404.html")

      e in ArgumentError -> conn
      |> put_status(:not_found)
      |> render(ErrorView, "404.html")
    end
  end
```

Instead of `Ecto.CastError` to raise a `400` I want it to raise `404`. However I can't satisfy my following test condition

```
  test "renders page not found when id is not all number", %{conn: conn} do
    assert_error_sent 404, fn ->
      get conn, url_path(conn, :show, "sdf2sd")
    end
  end
```

Since my custom exception handler didn't raise an exception.

The question is, how to raise a proper exception in my own custom exception handler to satisfy the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using wrong approach, rather than

```
  def call(conn, opts) do
    try do
      super(conn, opts)
    rescue
      e in Ecto.CastError -> conn
      |> put_status(:not_found)
      |> render(ErrorView, "404.html")

      e in ArgumentError -> conn
      |> put_status(:not_found)
      |> render(ErrorView, "404.html")
    end
  end
```

I should be using this block in my controller

```
  defimpl Plug.Exception, for: Ecto.CastError do
    def status(_exception), do: 404
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page on how to handle errors in Phoenix: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/errors.html

You may be able to override the defaults (defined [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto/blob/master/lib/phoenix_ecto/plug.ex)) so that Ecto.CastError results in a 404.

Comment: Thank you, helped me on finding where I'm doing wrong. Though to answer my question, this clue is not enough :)